# Whistling brakes after pad & rotor replacements

Tags: brakes, noise, replacements

I had recently had my brakes checked out and replaced following my mechanic's $800 recommendations.

I had had two brake pads replaced on the front tires and on the back tires I had the brake pads and rotors replaced.

Ever since the replacement, there is this very loud whistling noise that comes from the tires when I brake (I am not sure which tire(s), but I think it may be one or both of the back ones—again, not sure). I've never had this happen in the past.

My question is, **should I be concerned about this whistling noise?**

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be worried about it. Take it back to your mechanic and have them fix whatever is wrong. It is my belief, according to your words, they've not done something right. Don't mess around with brakes. Make them right. You paid for a service, a service which wasn't done correctly. Take it back to them and make them fix it.

Comment: Great advice which I believe I will take, thank you!